# Changing all time stamps with YYYY-mm-dd 24-mm-ss to YYYY-mm-dd+1 00-mm-ss

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Ive got a dataframe with strange hourly timestamps. It has both 00:00:00 and 24:00:00. It is as follows:

```
    TIMESTAMP           RECORD
2   2021-08-01 00:01:00 85878
3   2021-08-01 00:02:00 85879
4   2021-08-01 00:03:00 85880
5   2021-08-01 00:04:00 85881
6   2021-08-01 00:05:00 85882
...     ...     ...
1437    2021-08-01 23:56:00 87313
1438    2021-08-01 23:57:00 87314
1439    2021-08-01 23:58:00 87315
1440    2021-08-01 23:59:00 87316
1441    2021-08-01 24:00:00 87317
```

[image: Image of timestamp issue]

What I would like to do is if the hour is 24 then change it to 00 and the day to the next day.

Ive tried replacing all 24hrs etc with replace but cant get it to work and it would only tackle to hour issue, code I've tried is as follows:

```
data['TIMESTAMP'][10:11]=data['TIMESTAMP'][10:11].str.replace("24","00", case= False)
```

Comment: @MrFuppes done it, i think haha

Comment: @9769953 i wasnt able to convert to datetime with to_datetime and got this error "hour must be in 0..23: 2021-08-01 24:00:00". the first 5 rows of the table have the hours 00, "2021-08-01 00:01:00" for example.

MrFuppes has given a working solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split date and time, parse the date to datetime and add the time as a timedelta:

```
import pandas as pd

# split date and time
date_time = df['TIMESTAMP'].str.split(' ', expand=True)

# parse date to datetime and time to timedelta and combine
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(date_time[0]) + pd.to_timedelta(date_time[1])

df['TIMESTAMP']
0   2021-08-01 00:01:00
1   2021-08-01 00:02:00
2   2021-08-01 00:03:00
3   2021-08-01 00:04:00
4   2021-08-01 00:05:00
5   2021-08-01 23:56:00
6   2021-08-01 23:57:00
7   2021-08-01 23:58:00
8   2021-08-01 23:59:00
9   2021-08-02 00:00:00
Name: TIMESTAMP, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thanks @MrFuppes, it works well. Howcome all times are not shifted and only times with the hour 24? Im assuming its the to_timedelta() function, but looking at information on it I cant see why it would do this?

Comment: @JoshAlt basically yes, pd.to_timedelta gives you a [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) Series which you can add to (or subtract from) a datetime series - which in this case all have hour/minute/second = 00:00:00. If you now add 24 hours == one day to a date for example, the date flips forward by one day. Does this clarify?