# Using Pandas pd.to_dataframe() to format a date string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with a 'Date' column that has dates like this: '01/01/1970 01'.  This represents 'January 1st, 1970 01:00 AM' I was trying to format the Date column into datetime by doing `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')` However this is not working.  I get this error: `RetryError[<Future at 0x1b0dbc1eaf0 state=finished raised ValueError>]` I am guessing that something is wrong with my code.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: So with advice from Cimbali and TC Arlen I've discovered that the issue is the hour ending numbers goes from [01-24] and %H accepts [00-23].

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('01/01/1970 01')` works fine for me. Maybe add some dates for which you get errors?

Comment: I just found out it works for the first element if I do `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'][0], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')` but it breaks if i pass it the df['Date'] series.

Comment: Yes @ZacharyMcArthur, please try and figure out which values in the series cause the error and post some of those in your question. We can’t help you otherwise.

Comment: Also, feel free to use `errors=coerce` to force it to set the errored values as `NaT`, like this: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H', errors='coerce')`

Comment: Ah... it's messing up when the hour is 24.

Comment: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709896/changing-all-time-stamps-with-yyyy-mm-dd-24-mm-ss-to-yyyy-mm-dd1-00-mm-ss/68711376#68711376) - you can parse the date to datetime and the hour to timedelta and then add them together to get correct datetime datatype

Comment: Thank you @MrFuppes that was what I ended up doing and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

your question have mistake so correct it.

by the way your ans is:
`df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") print(df)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @harshit brahmbhatt You're incorrect.  `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H')`  Works just fine for the strings I had in my 'Date' column.  The issue was that my strings had hour values that went from 01-24 which breaks on 24 as %H expects values from 00-23